# What are the chances of female-to-male SOA/STD transmission during straight sex

Tags: medical-science, sexuality, hiv-aids, infection

SOA (https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seksueel_overdraagbare_aandoening)

When a male does intercourse with a female who is infected with SOA (SOA called in Belgium, not sure SOA is STD?).

How could/might a male get SOA?

- could male get SOA by having french kiss with female (tongue to tongue)?
- male giving vaginal cunnilingus?
- male giving vaginal message (with finger insertion)?

Comment: According to Google Translate, SOA is the Dutch abbreviation for STD or Sexually Transmitted Disease.  The answer to all of these is possibly, depends on the specific disease.  However, as stands, you don't have a notable claim here.  Perhaps [Health.SE](http://health.stackexchange.com/help) might better be able to answer these questions for you?